# Undefined references - I'm including correct header

Tags: qt, plugins

I'm trying to subclass from ProjectExplorer::ProjectExplorerPlugin but I'm getting error telling me about undefined references. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
class MyPluginPlugin : public ProjectExplorer::ProjectExplorerPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
};
```

error: undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN15ProjectExplorer21ProjectExplorerPluginC2Ev'

Comment: undefined references don't have anything to do with headers, but with linking, so how you link against libqtcreator's API's would be more relevant.

Comment: #FrankOsterfeld I suppose that I should provide some lib path, am I right?

Comment: What have you declared in your `LIBS` command in the `.pro` file?

Comment: @cmannett85 I don't have this (LIBS) variable set

Comment: I've never worked with Qt Creator's API, but presumably you will have to add: `LIBS += -L<path to lib> -l<name of lib>` to your pro file so it can link against it.

Comment: @cmannett85 I thought of it too but then when I've tried to search for this lib in qt there is only dll but not .a file. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might have to build it yourself, Digia must have thought that few people would want to link to it statically.

Comment: The ProjectExplorerPlugin library.

Comment: but even if I'll build it myself it will result in .dll file, which I already have. But there isn't .a file. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you build it as an archive (for static linking) it will be a `.a` file.  But to be honest, if you are making a Qt Creator plugin that relies on libraries that ship with Qt Creator - why would you bother statically linking to it anyway?

Comment: @cmannett85 I do not want to link it statically, I want to be able to link it dynamicaly

Comment: Then why would you need the `.a` file!?

Comment: @cmannett85 which file I'm supposed to specify while setting LIBS variable, i.e: LIBS += -L<path to lib> -l<name of lib>, can I specify the .dll file?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you don't get a compilation error, but an undefined reference usually means that your project knows where the header files are, but it doesn't know where the library is which contains the already compiled source code.

I've never written a plugin for Qt Creator but I've taken a quick look at its source code structure and I see the following options:

---

Option A)

There is a `projectexplorer.pro` file in Qt Creator's source under `src/plugins/projectexplorer`. You could manually build that project in order to get a ProjectExplorer.lib (plus a .dll or a .a) and then reference this library.
Example: Assuming the library would be created in the same directory as its .pro file (I have no idea if it is like that) and you created your plugin withing Qt Creator's source under `src/plugins/myplugin`, you would define your `LIBS` variable like this:

```
LIBS += -L../projectexplorer \
        -lProjectExplorer
```

The first line adds "../projectexplorer" as an additional library directory and the second line adds "ProjectExplorer" as a library to search in any of the defined directories (it automatically adds the OS-specific file extensions like .lib on windows etc).

Obviously if your project or the library is located somewhere else, you need to change the first line accordingly.

---

Option B)

You could include the source and header files of the `projectexplorer` directory to your own .pro file using the `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` variables. I'm not sure if this wouldn't interfere with any other plugins (including projectexplorer itself) though.

---

Option C)

There probably is a way to include the `projectexplorer.pro` file so that you have a master project which first builds the project explorer library and then your own plugin. This would be the safest way to go as it ensures the Project Explorer library is built and up-to-date before your own project is linked against it.
However I have limited experience on this.

*If anyone reading this can give a detailed explanation on this option, feel free to edit or provide your own answer.*

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer will check it as soon as I finish building my qt system. Thanks again.

Comment: Great advice. After adding the Libs in option A, the issue went away. I really had a hard time trying to figure out what undefined reference was referring to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Qt Creator built from source coded after April 2013 which includes [Commit: #66a3553 - make library and plugin dependencies declarative](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/commit/66a3553107a43f56372f756b218e268e71390d19), then you can simply specify dependencies for your plugin in its .pro file:

```
# myplugin.pro
QTC_PLUGIN_DEPENDS += \
    coreplugin \
    projectexplorer
```